# Variable width won't change after browser resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fluid

I have two li's which, by using javascript, is the same width of a certain li. The li is fluid css so it changes according to the browser width. The li becomes the same width as the other li when I load the page.

When I resize the browser, the width of the li doesn't change until I reload the page. How can I have my li automatically resize when the browser resizes instead of changing when it loads the page?

```
var width = $('li.more').width();
$('li.more ul li').css({'width':width+'px'});
```

Comment: Use `$(window).resize`

Comment: Oh wow.. that'll teach me for posting the comment before the answer :( fml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [**$(window).resize**](http://api.jquery.com/resize/) to achieve this:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
  width = $('li.more').width();
  $('li.more ul li').css({'width':width+'px'});
});
```

Here's a [**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/KNxLV/) of resize being used.

Answer (score 3):

http://api.jquery.com/resize/

```
$(window).resize(function() {
  width = $('li.more').width();
});
```

var `width` will change as you resize your browser